# need help in code to send sms to multiple contacts using arduino, gsm800, push button

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, button

[image: circuit diagram]

When button 1 is pressed, the message should be sent to 4 members. But we are receiving the message for one member and after some delay for the other members. But receiving to all members of contacts given in the code (Here numbers are not mentioned)

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int ButtonValue1=0;
int ButtonValue2=0;
int ButtonValue3=0;
int ButtonValue4=0;

int Button1=8;
int Button2=9;
int Button3=10;
int Button4=11;
int buz=12;
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void okcheck()
{
  unsigned char rcr;
  do{
    rcr = Serial.read();
  }while(rcr != 'K');
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(buz,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Button1,INPUT);
  pinMode(Button2,INPUT);
  pinMode(Button3,INPUT);
  pinMode(Button4,INPUT);

  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("INNOVATIVE CLG");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("BUS INFO SYSTEM");

  delay(1000); 
}

void loop() 
{
  ButtonValue1=digitalRead(Button1);
  ButtonValue2=digitalRead(Button2);
  ButtonValue3=digitalRead(Button3);
  ButtonValue4=digitalRead(Button4);

  if(ButtonValue1!=0)
  {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("BUS STARTED...");
    Serial.write("AT\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("ATE0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");   
    delay(100);
    Serial.write("GUD MNG.. BUS STARTED FROM STARTING POINT\r");   
    delay(100);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");    
    delay(100);
    Serial.write("GUD MNG.. BUS STARTED STARTING POINT\r");   
    delay(100);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");   
    delay(100);
    Serial.write("GUD MNG.. BUS STARTED STARTING POINT\r");   
    delay(100);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");    
    delay(100);
    Serial.write("GUD MNG.. BUS STARTED STARTING POINT\r");   
    delay(100);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
  }
  if(ButtonValue2!=0)
  {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("BUS IS @ 1st stage");
    Serial.write("AT\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("ATE0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");    
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write("BUS IS @ 1st stage\r");   
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");    
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write("BUS IS @ 1st stage\r");   
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");    
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write("BUS IS @ 1st stage\r");   
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
  }
  if(ButtonValue3!=0)
  {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("BUS IS @ 2nd stage");
    Serial.write("AT\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("ATE0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0\r\n");         okcheck();
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");    
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write("BUS IS @ 2nd stage\r");  
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
    Serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91...........\"\r");    
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write("BUS IS @ 2nd stage\r");   
    delay(1000);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);delay(1000);
  }
  if(ButtonValue4!=0)
  {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("BUS IS @ COLLEGE");
    digitalWrite(buz,LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(buz,HIGH);
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you write a `sendSMS(const char *number, const char *message)` function...

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor you code, It has become just too complicated for this kind of straight linear code! Your code must be organized better, Don't Repeat Yourself ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)); just by doing this you may find your error(s).

First lets fix your variables:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#define NUMBUTTS 4
int ButtonValues[NUMBUTTS]= {0,0,0,0};
int Buttons[NUMBUTTS]= {8,9,10,11};
int buz=12;
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

and add some new ones

```
String numbers[NUMBUTTS] = 
{
    "+91234567890",
    "+91234567890",
    "+91234567890",
    "+91234567890",
}

String msgs[NUMBUTTS-1] = 
{
   "GUD MNG.. BUS STARTED FROM STARTING POINT\r",
   "BUS IS @ 1st stage\r",
   "BUS IS @ 2nd stage\r",
}
```

next lets clean up your function:

```
void okcheck()
{
    unsigned char rcr = 0;
    while(rcr != 'K') // rcr can't be 'K' when it starts as 0
        rcr = Serial.read();
}
```

Setup needs to be changed now that we changed your vars:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(buz,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);

    for(int i=0; i<NUMBUTTS; i++)
        pinMode(Buttons[i],INPUT);


    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("INNOVATIVE CLG");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("BUS INFO SYSTEM");

    delay(1000);
}
```

now we need to extract duplicated code and put it in a function:

```
// common starting code.
void preamble()
{ 
    Serial.write("AT\r\n");
    okcheck();

    Serial.write("ATE0\r\n");
    okcheck();

    Serial.write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    okcheck();

    Serial.write("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0\r\n");
    okcheck();

    Serial.write("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0\r\n");
    okcheck();
}

// common message code
void send_sms(String& msg)
{
    String prefix = "AT+CMGS=\"";   
    preamble();

    for(int i=0;i<NUMBUTTS;i++)
    {
        Serial.write(prefix+numbers[i]+"\"\r");   
        delay(100);

        Serial.write(msg);   
        delay(100);

        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(2000)
    }
}
```

now we need to fix up loop():

```
void loop() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<NUMBUTTS; i++)
    {
        ButtonValues[i]=digitalRead(Buttons[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<NUMBUTTS-1; i++)
    {
        if(ButtonValues[i]!=0)
        {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print(msgs[i]);
            send_sms(msgs[i]);
        }
    }

    //special case for button4
    if(ButtonValue[3]!=0)
    {
         lcd.clear();
         lcd.print("BUS IS @ COLLEGE");
         digitalWrite(buz,LOW);
         delay(1000);
         digitalWrite(buz,HIGH);
    }
}
```

Now your program logic is separate from the code that sends the messages, and you can test each in isolation from each other. You can test that send_sms() actually sends SMSs. Then you can see if your logic does what you think it does; by either replacing send_sms() with a test stub, or just by inspection.

With clean code it should be easier to spot your problem. The code looks like it should work, so I would guess that the modem itself may be causing the delays, maybe it takes a while to send a message and you are queuing them up and it takes a few seconds to get through each one, its possible that not all get send because one or more gets dropped while it is busy sending another. Hard to know without looking at the documentation for your module.

Your diagram looks like it is hooked up wrong, you have TX-> RX, but MOSI -> TX; Serial.read() reads from RX not MOSI, so i don't know how checkok() doesn't just loop forever, since you left the arduino RX floating.

Comment: The code has occurred error while compiling. There is no declaration of ButtonValue(3) in the code, but it is used in the special case for button 4.

Comment: @PavanKumar ButtonValue_s_ is an array and ButtonValues[3] __is__ definitely in the code; there is no guarantee that i didn't make a typo or error you might have to fix.